# How to bootstrap Angular from index.html?

Tags: angular, bootstrapping

I need to conditionally include a script that my app uses via a global variable. I.e., bootstrapping must happen after it has been included.

In AngularJS, I accomplished this with the following script in `index.html`:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

...

<script>

    ...

    appendScript(
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=" + global_language +"&region=" + global_region,
        function() { angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector("#myApp"), ["myApp"]); }
    );

    function appendScript(url, onload) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = url;
        script.async = false;
        script.onload = onload;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
</script>
```

I am migrating towards Angular 4. My new app has been created with the Angular CLI. Thus, `main.ts` contains:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

However, `platformBrowserDynamic` is not defined in `index.html`, which is not surprising as Angular CLI put no Angular-specific scripts in there.

So, what happens now is that the library's global variable ("google") will generally be undefined when Angular bootstraps. Only by chance it is sometimes already defined.

How can I bootstrap Angular from `index.html`? Or maybe there is a different way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0):

This does not exactly answer my question, but I have found a workaround. In `main.ts`, do this:

```js
declare var google: any;

const interval = setInterval(
    () => {
        if (typeof google === "object") {

            if (environment.production) {
                enableProdMode();
            }

            platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
                .catch(err => console.log(err));

            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    },
    20
);
```

The same with some extra code to determine a sensible interval size:

```js
declare var google: any;

let failCount = 0;
const interval = setInterval(
    () => {
        if (typeof google === "object") {
            alert(`Success after ${failCount} fail(s).`);

            if (environment.production) {
                enableProdMode();
            }

            platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
                .catch(err => console.log(err));

            clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
            failCount++;
        }
    },
    20
);
```